# How to install daemontools on ubuntu or debian from source

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation, compiling, daemontools

I am installing D.J.B.'s `daemontools` on an ubuntu 10.04 server (64 bit).

(This question is about `daemontools`, which is a free and open software for managing UNIX services. It is not about 'DAEMON tools', which is a commercial software for disk images, running on windows.)

I first installed the build-essential package and afterwards followed the instructions on http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/install.html 1:1, but it fails:

```
Script started on Sa 28 Apr 2012 21:41:34 CEST
root@daemontools1:/# mkdir -p /package
root@daemontools1:/#      chmod 1755 /package
root@daemontools1:/#      cd /package
root@daemontools1:/package# wget http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/daemontools-0.76.ta ^Mr.gz
--2012-04-28 21:42:10--  http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/daemontools-0.76.tar.gz
Resolving cr.yp.to... 131.193.32.142, 80.101.159.118
Connecting to cr.yp.to|131.193.32.142|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 36975 (36K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `daemontools-0.76.tar.gz'

^M 0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s              ^M58% [=====================>              $

2012-04-28 21:42:11 (125 KB/s) - `daemontools-0.76.tar.gz' saved [36975/36975]

root@daemontools1:/package# gunzip daemontools-0.76.tar
root@daemontools1:/package#      tar -xpf daemontools-0.76.tar
root@daemontools1:/package#      rm -f daemontools-0.76.tar
root@daemontools1:/package#      cd admin/daemontools-0.76
root@daemontools1:/package/admin/daemontools-0.76#
root@daemontools1:/package/admin/daemontools-0.76#
root@daemontools1:/package/admin/daemontools-0.76# package/install
Linking ./src/* into ./compile...
Compiling everything in ./compile...
sh find-systype.sh > systype
rm -f compile
sh print-cc.sh > compile
chmod 555 compile
./compile byte_chr.c
./compile byte_copy.c
./compile byte_cr.c
./compile byte_diff.c
./compile byte_rchr.c
./compile fmt_uint.c
./compile fmt_uint0.c
./compile fmt_ulong.c
rm -f makelib
sh print-ar.sh > makelib
chmod 555 makelib
./compile scan_ulong.c
./compile str_chr.c
./compile str_diff.c
./compile str_len.c
./compile str_start.c
./makelib byte.a byte_chr.o byte_copy.o byte_cr.o byte_diff.o \
        byte_rchr.o fmt_uint.o fmt_uint0.o fmt_ulong.o scan_ulong.o str_chr.o \
        str_diff.o str_len.o str_start.o
rm -f choose
cat warn-auto.sh choose.sh \
        | sed s}HOME}"`head -1 home`"}g \
        > choose
chmod 555 choose
./choose c trydrent direntry.h1 direntry.h2 > direntry.h
./compile envdir.c
rm -f load
sh print-ld.sh > load
chmod 555 load
./compile alloc.c
./compile alloc_re.c
./compile buffer.c
./compile buffer_0.c
./compile buffer_1.c
./compile buffer_2.c
./compile buffer_get.c
./compile buffer_put.c
./compile buffer_read.c
./compile buffer_write.c
./compile coe.c
./compile env.c
./compile error.c
./compile error_str.c
./compile fd_copy.c
./compile fd_move.c
./choose cl trymkffo hasmkffo.h1 hasmkffo.h2 > hasmkffo.h
./compile fifo.c
./choose cl tryflock hasflock.h1 hasflock.h2 > hasflock.h
./compile lock_ex.c
./compile lock_exnb.c
./compile ndelay_off.c
./compile ndelay_on.c
./compile open_append.c
./compile open_read.c
./compile open_trunc.c
./compile open_write.c
./compile openreadclose.c
./compile pathexec_env.c
./compile pathexec_run.c
pathexec_run.c: In function ‘pathexec_run’:
pathexec_run.c:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execve’
./compile chkshsgr.c
chkshsgr.c: In function ‘main’:
chkshsgr.c:10: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getgroups’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:266: note: expected ‘__gid_t *’ but argument is of type ‘short int *’
chkshsgr.c:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setgroups’
./load chkshsgr
./chkshsgr || ( cat warn-shsgr; exit 1 )
./choose clr tryshsgr hasshsgr.h1 hasshsgr.h2 > hasshsgr.h
./compile prot.c
prot.c: In function ‘prot_gid’:
prot.c:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setgroups’
prot.c:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setgid’
prot.c: In function ‘prot_uid’:
prot.c:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setuid’
./compile readclose.c
./compile seek_set.c
seek_set.c: In function ‘seek_set’:
seek_set.c:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘lseek’
./compile sgetopt.c
./compile sig.c
./choose cl trysgprm hassgprm.h1 hassgprm.h2 > hassgprm.h
./compile sig_block.c
./choose cl trysgact hassgact.h1 hassgact.h2 > hassgact.h
./compile sig_catch.c
./compile sig_pause.c
./compile stralloc_cat.c
./compile stralloc_catb.c
./compile stralloc_cats.c
./compile stralloc_eady.c
./compile stralloc_opyb.c
./compile stralloc_opys.c
./compile stralloc_pend.c
./compile strerr_die.c
./compile strerr_sys.c
./compile subgetopt.c
./choose cl trywaitp haswaitp.h1 haswaitp.h2 > haswaitp.h
./compile wait_nohang.c
./compile wait_pid.c
./makelib unix.a alloc.o alloc_re.o buffer.o buffer_0.o buffer_1.o \
        buffer_2.o buffer_get.o buffer_put.o buffer_read.o buffer_write.o \
        coe.o env.o error.o error_str.o fd_copy.o fd_move.o fifo.o lock_ex.o \
        lock_exnb.o ndelay_off.o ndelay_on.o open_append.o open_read.o \
        open_trunc.o open_write.o openreadclose.o pathexec_env.o \
        pathexec_run.o prot.o readclose.o seek_set.o sgetopt.o sig.o \
        sig_block.o sig_catch.o sig_pause.o stralloc_cat.o stralloc_catb.o \
        stralloc_cats.o stralloc_eady.o stralloc_opyb.o stralloc_opys.o \
        stralloc_pend.o strerr_die.o strerr_sys.o subgetopt.o wait_nohang.o \
        wait_pid.o
./load envdir unix.a byte.a
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]
/usr/bin/ld: make: *** [envdir] Error 1
Copying commands into ./command...
cp: cannot stat `compile/svscan': No such file or directory
```

I also tried to do it on debian squeeze, the result is similar: http://pastebin.com/VNAWLU57

I know I can install daemontools from the ubuntu and also debian repository, but how do I compile it myself?

Comment: Why do you want to install daemontools on your Linux machine? What good stuff does it bring?

Comment: @jippie I like to run services on every distribution the same way in a simple and solid manner that does not change with every new os release. The author lists some advantages here: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/faq/create.html#why

Comment: How about this, [official packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=daemontools)? ([See also this](http://smarden.org/pape/Debian/daemontools.html))

Comment: @sr_ yes, I will use the packages if I find no solution how to compile myself, thank you.

Comment: `ld` segfaulting is rather strange. Can you try upgrading your toolchain? (This type of thing is usually not a problem with the source code itself, more the environment you're building in (compiler, toolchain, possibly even hardware issues))

Comment: Why do you need to use daemon tools? Are you just needing to mount ISO files?

Comment: @LVLAaron The one you are thinking of is a totally different software. This question is about daemontools, which is a linux software for managing services (daemons), not ISOs. See http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

Comment: Oh, sorry. Actually looks pretty interesting!

Comment: The same should work on Ubuntu.  Do `apt-get install build-essential` instead for step 1 then do the rest the same.

Comment: @Mikel I had not mentioned it but this was the first I installed in all ubuntu / debian examples. I have updated the question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the meantime I was able to compile and install on Debian Squeeze, Ubuntu and also CentOS 6.0 and it works. I guess the patch from http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/setting-up-djbdns-on-linux was fixing it.

1) Install a toolchain

For Debian and Ubuntu: `apt-get install build-essential`

For CentOS `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

2) Follow the instructions on http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/install.html but do not yet execute the `package/install` command

3) Apply the patch from http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/setting-up-djbdns-on-linux to `src/conf-cc`

4) Now execute the `package/install` command.

Comment: Brilliant. Can't say I would have found that out on my own. Thanks @mit and Tony

Comment: I am glad it helped and we are lucky the linked websites are still around.